# keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to generate a signed bundle or apk. But when I am trying to create a new keystore file. I am getting this error. `keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect`.
I don't know what is wrong with it. I have kept the both password of keystore path and key same. someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try Build > Clean project.
This is written in Preparing for Release: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing#clean-up-your-project-directories